# Does increment in pointer not same as that of integer?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

*Consider the code below:*

```
void increment(int* a)
{
    printf("%d\n",a);
    *a=*a+1;
}
int main()
{
    int a=10;
    int* p=&a;
    increment(&a);
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

*This increments a to be 11 but this :*

```
void increment(int* a)
{
    printf("%d\n",a);
     *a++;
}
int main()
{
    int a=10;
    int* p=&a;
    increment(&a);
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code generates value as 10.

Is the pointer arithmetic not like integer arithmetic or am I missing something here??

Comment: @Bathsheba yeah ... `***a=*a+1;**<br>`  WT*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `printf("%d\n",a);` does not print the value of the integer pointed to by `a`.  As written, it invokes undefined behavior.

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)a);
```

would print the value of the pointer, ie the address of the integer variable.

```
printf("%d\n", *a);
```

would print the value of the integer.

Futhermore, `*a=*a+1;` is not the same as `*a++;`.  Due to operator precedence rules, `*a++` is parsed as `*(a++)`, the pointer is incremented, not the value pointed to.  You could use `++*a;` as a shorthand for `*a = *a + 1;`, and other variants are possible: `++a[0]`, `a[0]++`, `(*a)++`, but the preferred solution is:

```
*a += 1;
```

Comment: `(*a)++` would work; so would `a[0]++`.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing operator priorities. The `(*a)++;` is something totally different from `*a++`.
The first one increments value at address `a`, second one post increment `a` and gets value at the original address.

Comment: what does *a++ actually do it increments the address?? if so how ?? Im not able to contemplate it

Comment: `a` is just local variable. It gets incremented but it's not used anymore, so no harm. If you write to it, it will change memory after the original variable